# How to install vtkplotter with Python 3.8.5?

Tags: python

I have Python 3.8.5

How can I install the package vtkplotter with this Python version?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I type `pip3 install vtkplotter` I got an error _ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtkplotter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtkplotter

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `vtkplotter` has migrated to `vedo` ([Link](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo) to GitHub repo with installation instructions). Maybe you are better off using `vedo` for newer Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use pip or conda or whatever to install your package.

If you find that a certain version of Python is not compatible with a specific version of a library, you can make a virtualenvironment with a specific python version that is compatible with the package, activate the virtual environment, and then install your package.

Answer (score 0):

you can install it by [conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/vtkplotter)

To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
     conda install -c conda-forge vtkplotter
     conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 vtkplotter
```